# Dividing canvas to regions, then attracting nearby items to the nearest region?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm creating GUI using python tkinter to visualize Road Scenarios (the main vehicle & close by vehicles). I draw in the canvas lines to give road top view (as the Picture below).
The user can insert a rectangle (vehicle) then move it freely on the canvas.

What I want is: after the user moves the rectangle to where ever he wants, the y coordination of the rectangle will relocate to the nearest lane, to have a nice looking png at the end.

My thought about it:

1. Divide the canvas to regions (each Region represent a lane)
2. Create a function which knows when the rectangle finished moving, then modify the y coordination of it to the nearest Region (lane).

Not sure how to apply this in Code though. Any useful canvas functions or another approach are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I mentioned at the question worked for me.

1. A list identifing the y-axis sides of each Region was created.
2. After creating the items needed, they all share a common Tag.
3. Choose which part of the items you want to consider the original Point (which will be used later as the item's current location). Canvas.bboc(CURRENT) can be sufficient to do that.
4. Detect when does the item enter a Region, by comparing if the item's current Location is within the boundaries of a Region.
5. Use Canvas.coords() or Cancas.move() methods to move the items at the middle of the regoin they have entered.